# Accessing message in WCF service when I get serializing exception

Tags: .net, json, wcf, rest, ierrorhandler

In WCF service I have custom `IErrorHandler`. Works great and I fixed lot's of stuff by logging errors. Last error I'm getting is serialization exception:

```
Unexpected end of file. Following elements are not closed: Source, item, root.

There was an error deserializing the object of type System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[My.Web.Services.Dto.Log, My.Web.Services.Dto, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]. Unexpected end of file. Following elements are not clo
```

That tells me that message didn't come in properly from a client. Is there any way I can see what message it was? Can I access HTTP post paramteres from inside `IErrorHandler` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a WCF [MessageInspector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa717047.aspx) , (IDispatchMessageInspector) it will let you access the message before it is deserialized, see the AfterReceiveRequest method in the linked example. Ian Picknell has a more lengthy [post](http://ianpicknell.blogspot.it/2011/03/implementing-idispatchmessageinspector.html) with more details

Comment: What if I don't want to log all messages, but only the one that triggered the exception? How/where do I store the message body so that I can access it later in the `IErrorHandler`?

Answer (score 1):

[IErrorHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.ierrorhandler.aspx) is called before the response message is handed to the channgel stack where serialization takes place. So your custom error handler will not be called if serialization encounters a problem. Your best bet is to use [tracing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa738639.aspx) to log messages and inspect them.

Comment: Tracing is not practical, I get 1-2 per day with thousands of requests. Also, it's messages that clients POST, not response. How come I see this exception in IErrorHandler if it is called before?

Comment: IErrorHandler applies server side only. Do you have a custom serializer that reads from a file or something?

Comment: This is WCF REST service. Client POST and GET different messages. Error clearly states that it's because of serializing one of my objects. Looking at object name I can tell that error was during POST. So, built-on .NET serializer failed. I want to see what the message was

Comment: This is not WCF client, regular HTTP clients: Mobile devices, etc. Plain vanilla REST endpoint.

Comment: Apparently either the clients are not sending you the whole thing for the serializer on the server to deserialize the message or some packets are getting lost in the transmission. Tracing may help or a protocol analyzer to see if you can gather any clues from the received packets in case it is data related. However, it could also be an intermittent issue with the network or the clients that you may not be able to solve but to live with.

Comment: So, there is no way I can get RAW request?